# JSON Array with RequestParams in Android Asynchronous Http Client

Tags: android, json, http-post

I have trouble to send a JSON POST Request to my server.

My server accept a POST with application/json as type and an example would be like this:

```
{
  "name": "Group4",
  "users": [
     {"email": "user@example.org"},
     {"email": "user2@example.org"},
  ]
}
```

If I send this by a REST client I get 200 OK as response, everything fine.

My Android client uses the *Android Async HTTP Library* (http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) and a documentation to the RequestParams class is here https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/RequestParams.html

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
String userName = getUserName();
List<String> userList = getUserList();
params.put("name", userName);
JSONArray users = new JSONArray();
for(String user : userList) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("email", user);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // ...
    }
    users.put(obj);
}
params.put("users", users);
```

I thought this will create exactly a JSON like my example. I don't know if I have the possibility to get a JSON string of this RequestParams. I only can access the parameter as a String:

```
name=Test&users=[{"email":"user@example.org"}, {"email":"user2@example.org"}]
```

My server don't even accept the request and fails directly with the error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

The problem has to be at the point where I create the RequestParams. Can someone tell me what is wrong with that? I thought I have to create an array with name "users" and then add objects in it with key-value items.

Answer (score 3):

Just put `List<>` to your `RequestParams`. Here is the example:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // Ordered collection

list.add("Java");
list.add("C");

params.put("languages", list); 

//above code will generate url params: "languages[0]=Java&languages[1]=C"
```

So you don't need to add it manually using Loop sequence.
See the docs [here](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/RequestParams.html)

Answer (score -1):

Will recommend to use Volley for Async calls in Android https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html